# Is there any keyboard shortcut to launch vscode terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to launch VS code terminal through keyboard keys. Is there any shortcut to achieve this behaviour.

Comment: Use Ctrl+' (default). Pretty sure this can be changed somwhere in the settings.

Comment: No, tried with Ctrl +. it doesn't work in windows.

Comment: Hmm, strange, I also tried it on Windows. Ctrl + back tick maybe? One way to see the shortcut is to hover your mouse over the terminal tab, when it is visible in the screen.

Comment: yeah, i tried with alternate  ctrl+shift+, no luck. it rather increased the font size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on Windows, it should be

```
Ctrl + `
```

on OSX, it should be

```
⌃ + ` // ⌃ is control key
```

Reference:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf
- https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf